# conditional formatting using nested if with multiple conditions in excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, multiple-conditions, nested-if

I'm trying to format cells in a column using the conditional formatting tool in Excel.

In order for the cell to be filled in green it must meet the following conditions:

- If field in column B is between 80 or 100 % show green
- If field in column A is under 3 months old and adjacent field in column B is between 60 and 100% show green
- If field in column A is under 1 months old and adjacent field in column B is between 40 and 100% show green

If I only create one rule for each condition it works. See below:

Rule 1

```
=IF(B1>=0.8,IF(B1<=1,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

Rule 2

```
=IF(A1<3,IF(B1>=0.6,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

Rule 3

```
=IF(A1<1,IF(B1>=0.4,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

When I combine all the rules it will only return whichever condition is first. See below:

```
=IF(B1>=0.8,IF(B1<=1,TRUE,
IF(B1>=0.6,IF(A1<3,TRUE,
IF(B1>=0.4,IF(A1<1,TRUE))))),FALSE)
```

I have also attempted using `AND`statements. Again the same issue, when I ran the second line to test if the condition would even work by itself it returned nothing. Please see below:

```
=IF(B1>=0.8,IF(B1<=1,TRUE,
IF(A1<3,IF(AND(B1>=0.6,B1<=1),TRUE,
IF(A1<1,IF(AND(B1>=0.4,B1<=1),TRUE,FALSE))))),FALSE)
```

Any advice on this would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're after.

```
=IF(OR(AND(B2>=0.8,B2<=1),AND(A2<3,B2>=0.6),AND(A2<1,B2>=0.4)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

**Breakdown**: Combined the 2 conditions of your 3 rules using `AND`. Then added an `OR` as you want the same highlighting regardless of which one is true.